# Automatically fit document on smaller paper size (LibreOffice Writer)

Tags: linux, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

The whole point of the system of European paper sizes is that all have exactly the same ratio. So, theoretically, you can print an A3 document on an A4 sheet and it will not be distorted — it will simply be smaller.

Practically, however, I cannot seem to find a way to do this on Linux Mint, Libre Office Writer 4.2.

How can I print a larger document on a smaller paper size in LibreOffice Writer?

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard task for printers / printer drivers to adapt the printing data to the media size. So, the solution depends on the printer you're using and the capabilities of the printer and the printer driver. In LO Writer, there's no feature to "zoom" the complete document, affecting every page element (font sizes, tables, pictures and so on). Things are different in Calc: there, you can tell LO Calc to shrink the content when printing (Menu `Format` -> `Page...` -> `Sheet`).

Answer (score -1):

**This is a bad solution. In fact, it is not a solution at all, it is just a workaround. I am still looking for a better solution.**

Export the document as a PDF file. Evince (Document Viewer) automatically shrinks pages to the paper size when printing by default.